# Bookshelf.js, query based on joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I have the following schema for an Analytics project:

Visits have Sessions, and Sessions have Session Data.

I'm trying to write a Bookshelf query that will get me the latest Session Data entry for a Visit, without resorting to an entirely 'raw' query.

So the SQL query goes like this:

```
select sd.* from session_data sd
join sessions s on sd.session_id = s.id
join visits v on s.visit_id = v.id
where v.id = 28
having max(sd.created_at)
```

All of my Bookshelf models have the appropriate relations, but I'm just not sure how to structure the query in "bookshelf speak"?

```
var Visit = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'visits',
  hasTimestamps: true,

  Sessions: function() {
        return this.hasMany('Session');
    }

});

var Session = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'sessions',
  hasTimestamps: true,

  visit: function() {
    return this.belongsTo('Visit');
  },

    sessionData: function() {
        return this.hasMany('SessionData');
    }

});

var SessionData = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'session_data',
  hasTimestamps: true,

  session: function() {
    return this.belongsTo('Session');
  }

});
```

Comment: I am not familiar with MySQL idiosyncrasies but I think even there the `HAVING` clause requires an operator, like `HAVING max(sd.created_at) <operator: =, <, >, ..> <some date expression>`.

Anyway I think bookshelf does not go that far and you'll have to work with que knex based query builder.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you about there:

```
Visit.where('id', visitID)
    .fetch({ withRelated: [{
        'sessions.session_data': function(qb) {
            qb.orderBy('created_at', 'desc').limit(1);
        }
    }] })
    .then(function(visit) {
        var session = visit.related('sessions').at(0), // Get an arbitrary session.
            sessionData = session.related('session_data');
    });
```

sessionData will be an array, but should always be no longer than one element.